# how to open Jupyter notebook in chrome on windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook

On my Windows PC, i have anaconda installed and when I open a jupyter notebook, it opens up in internet explorer, but I would like to use Chrome instead. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 87):

If you haven't already, create a notebook config file by running

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Then, edit the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` found in the `.jupyter` folder of your home directory.

You need to change the line `# c.NotebookApp.browser = ''` to `c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/path/to/your/chrome.exe %s'`

On windows 10, Chrome should be located `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe` but check on your system to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need a more basic explanation. How do L create the config file? When I open a jupyter notebook in internet explorer and run that code I get an error...

Comment: Where do i run `jupyter notebook --generate-config`? in the command prompt and within a jupyter notebook they both return an error

Comment: OK, i ran the code in the anaconda prompt, and created the config file, then replaced the code as stated above, but it didn't work. Jupyter still opens in explorer...

Comment: I just tested it myself on my windows 10 machine and it works for me. You should run the `jupyter notebook --generate-config` in the same prompt that you use to launch the notebook (so I presume in this case the anaconda prompt). Did you ensure that you removed the `#` in front of the line like in my example? If you leave the hash then the line is still commented out. Also make sure that you are using forward slashes and not backward slashes, and that you included the ` %s` part.

Comment: @LouiseDavies What is '%s' used for?

Comment: @Jia Guo It's the string substitution token in Python. I may have remembered incorrectly - but I think it is because the `browser` option is literally the command Jupyter uses to create the web browser, and because we want our browser to open with the Jupyter page already open we need to pass the notebook URL to the Chrome executable. Rather than manually specify this ourselves, Jupyter can auto-insert the argument into the string so that when Chrome is opened it opens on the notebook URL.

Comment: Any way to do the same on macOS? I've tried the same thing, but it stopped lunching in Safari but it didn't lunch in Chrome though, so I kept it to default.

Comment: I created this video which I thought might be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4LCiu6LzEU

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it's a lifesaver for those forced to work on company laptops, where we cannot change the default browser.

Comment: Easiest way to do this in windows is 

go to the search bar in windows type default apps then choose chrome as default app in browser. this will change your browser to chrome and then when you enter jupyter notebook in anaconda it will automatically open in chrome. 

I hope it helps.

Comment: @user3568896 if you're able and willing then changing the default browser is an easier solution, but as other commenters have stated sometimes one is unable or unwilling to change the OS default browser, hence my answer

Answer (score 34):

Just make chrome as a default browser and launch the jupyter . It will work

To Make Google chrome a default browser , follow steps

1. Click on **Customize and Control Google chrome** (The vertical three dots on the Upper right corner of your google chrome browser)
2. Click on **Settings** and scroll down to  **Default browser**.
3. Change the value of the default browser to **Google Chrome** by clicking on whatever your default browser is there and selecting `Google Chrome`.

### Note:

In windows 10, you will be redirected to **Default apps** under your computer's **Settings**. Please scroll down to **Web browser** and Select **Google Chrome**. If promted, Click on **OK** else just **close** the settings tab and return to your `command` or `anaconda prompt` and type `jupyter notebook` as usual. A new jupyter notebook tab should open in Google Chrome now.

Comment: Please, explain better your answer, and provide a method to set the browser as default. Maybe the OP doesn't know how to do it. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This wasn't sufficient for me, either. Chrome is my default browser and it's still opening up in stupid Microsoft Edge.

Comment: This doesn't work for Windows 10 nor Ubuntu 18 in my tests. Writing a proper config file was needed everytime.

Comment: In Windows 10 you must also change the default app for .html files to chrome. This can be done in the "Choose default apps by file type" section of the default apps settings page.

Comment: Search for "Default apps" in Start menu. Scroll down to the default browser and change it to Chrome. You are then all set to go.

Answer (score 28):

For those who still have trouble launching Chrome automatically from cmd, try replacing

```
# c.NotebookApp.browser =''
```

in the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` with

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'chrome'
```

or the appropriate location, there shouldn't be need to install anything via pip.

Ref: https://support.anaconda.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2925919-change-default-browser-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not sure why I had to do this when the simpler method seemed to work for others, but this works for me.  Thanks!

Comment: yup, this is also working for me. I am using windows 10 pro version 1909, conda --version 4.7.5

Comment: Only this worked on Windows 10 with jupyter pip installed.
Setting `c.NotebookApp.browser` to a path (with or without trailing %s did not work.

Comment: also working on win11, anaconda version 2.5.2. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Create and edit the jupyter notebook config file with the following steps:

- Launch **Anaconda Prompt**
- Type `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
- Type `notepad path_to_file/jupyter_notebook_config.py` to open it (change `path_to_file`)
- Modify `#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''` to `c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'`
- Save the file and close it

Jupyter notebook will now use Chrome.

**EDIT**

In Windows 10 I had to type

- `notepad .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

And substitute the line with

- `c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'`

Comment: This worked. Just check the folder path where Chrome is installed in your PC.

Answer (score 10):

step1: Go to search menu of windows and type default app.

step 2: go to WEB BROWSER title and change it to Google Chrome.

step3: Go to search menu of windows and type jupyter notebook

This will open the jupyter notebook in Google Chrome

Comment: Even though chrome was already set as my default browser repeating these steps solved the problem for me

Answer (score 9):

- Run the jupyter notebook `--generate-config` command on the anaconda prompt.
- Then edit the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file.

Find the c.NotebookApp.Browser like this:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'c:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
```

Works on mine.

Comment: This does not allow me to open automatically

Answer (score 7):

Take any html file on your computer and set the default browser to open html files to chrome. This will automatically open jupyter notebook with chrome. Worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

For windows set the default browser to open html files to Chrome.   Configuration   > Default Apps   >  Default Apps by File Type. Worked for me.

Comment: This should have been the approved solution! Easiest way to do the trick!

Answer (score 7):

I found an easier solution that may help beginners to coding.

go to

```
C:\Users\'-your user-'\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
```

and find a file named

```
nbserver-6176-open.html
```

then

Right-click > open with > Choose default program...

Here, what ever you choose would be saved on your Windows to open all HTML files; therefore when you run Jupyter notebook, it would open in the program you want.

Comment: Just create a html file (you may create txt and then change it's extension to html from txt).

Comment: Thanks Maz, your answer really helped

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to change anything in the jupyter config code, you just have to make Chrome as your default browser in the setting. Jupyter opens whichever is the default.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason Louise's answer didn't work for me I had to:

-Open anaconda prompt and generate the config file for Jupyter: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

-Open the newly created config file at: `C:\Users\builder\.juptyer\jupyter_notebook_config.py`

-Add the following to the file:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'chrome'
```

Answer (score 4):

I just followed 2 steps and everythings working as expected

step-1
set chrome executable path environment varibale, in my case it is(you can test it in cmd by typing chrome and enter, it will open your chrome browser if path set properly):-

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

step-2 just run below command and you are good to go

```
jupyter notebook --browser chrome
```

Answer (score 2):

See response on this thread that has worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275293/11141700

**NOTE - Additional STEP 3 that has made the difference for me compared to similar approaches suggested here**

In short:

**Step 1 - Generate config for Jupyter Notebook:**

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

**Step 2 - Edit the config file using "nano" or other editor**

The config fileshould be under your home directory under ".jupyter" folder:

```
~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

**Step 3 - Disable launching browser by redirecting file**

First comment out the line, then change True to False:

```
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

**Step 4 - add a line to your .bashrc file to set the BROWSER path**

```
export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
```

For me it was Chrome under my Windows Program File. Otherwise any linux installation under WSL doesn't have a native browser to launch, so need to set it to the Windows executable.

**Step 5 - restart .bashrc**

```
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

In the windows when we open jupyter notebook in command prompt we can see the instructions in first 10 lines in that there is one instruction- "to open notebook, open this file in browser file://C:/Users/{username}/appdata/roaming/jupyetr/runtime/nbserver-xywz-open.html " , open this html with browser of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I just set chrome as my default browser and jupyter launches in Chrome now.

However, we have also the following approach, but it did not work for me:

"CONDA version 4.7.5 and jupyter 6.0.0. - Windows 10"

1) Open Anaconda and launch your environment in terminal

[image]

2) Create config file and open file in notepad

[image]

3) Modify line of NotebookApp with chrome and save modification

[image]

4) Launch Jupyter

:( ... but it still launches in Mozilla.

Comment: Setting default browser as Chrome didnt help me, but setting html app to open by default in Chrome did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all these "solutions" and still doesn't work, try to open the url over HTTP (not HTTPS <-- the real problem with chrome) and using an Incognito window (press Ctrl + Shift + N on Chrome)

This worked for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue Installed Anaconda in new laptop and when started Jupyter notebook by default it opened in edge, given my default browser is Chrome.

I just change 'default browser' setting to edge and then again switch to chrome.
After this trick, Jupyter is opening in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

On my (somewhat older and outdated) Anaconda installation on Windows 10 using the `--browser` option did not work. I could not use Jupyter Lab due to an outdated browser.

So I had to look for an alternative which for me was setting the environment variable `BROWSER` pointing to the browser program file. So by performing a

```
set BROWSER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

in a command shell (or Powershell with the appropriate command), Jupyter [Lab] afterwards started by using the MS Edge browser, just as wanted. Any other browser can be used by providing the path to it via setting `BROWSER`. I've adjusted my batch file accordingly so I can now use Jupyter Lab.