# Plotly Graphs not showing in Jupyterlab despite installed extensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a weird problem. Jupyterlab doesn't show plotly graphs, but in Jupyter notebook, everything works fine.
I've searched everywhere, many said plotly-extension should be installed. I have installed plotly extension. The notebook I'm working on is trusted. I don't know what should I do.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=[2, 1, 4, 3]))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=[1, 4, 3, 2]))
fig.update_layout(title = 'Hello Figure')
fig.show()
```

[This is what jupyterlab shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/916OJ.png)

Comment: You can check [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35) for the extensions that need to be installed. Additionally you need to install [node](https://nodejs.org/).

Comment: You can use lower level plotly and call `iplot` to show the figure.  `from plotly.offline import iplot`. Then `iplot(fig)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and, as I am using Anaconda, in the "Server" environment, apart from installing Plotly, I installed the following JupyterLab extension(s):

- `jupyterlab-plotly`

  ```
  jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.1
  ```
- `plotlywidget` [optional]

  ```
  jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager plotlywidget@4.14.1
  ```

In order to install the extensions [`nodejs`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs) is required.

For a more detailed answer [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65478275/7109869).