# Jupyterlab Plotly extension install: JupyterLab failed to build

Tags: installation, plotly, jupyter-lab

I try to install Plotly extension to Jupiterlab. After I installed every package (Anaconda, jupyterlab "ipywidgets>=7.5") I try to install "jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3" but I got an error message: RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

I try to identify the problem from the Log file, but I have no idea what to do next

The log file:

```
Yarn configuration loaded.
Node v15.12.0

 "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\npm.CMD" pack jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3
npm notice 
npm notice package: jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 156B  README.md                            
npm notice 6.3kB dist/javascript-renderer-extension.js
npm notice 1.0kB package.json                         
npm notice 545B  style/index.css                      
npm notice 1.0kB style/plotly.svg                     
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          jupyterlab-plotly                       
npm notice version:       4.14.3                                  
npm notice filename:      jupyterlab-plotly-4.14.3.tgz            
npm notice package size:  3.1 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 9.1 kB                                  
npm notice shasum:        bb424a50226c2ce1b816f061a8123f0f42418fc0
npm notice integrity:     sha512-6ZdmIQ5fDiBTY[...]nASwRNCf1U1Cg==
npm notice total files:   5                                       
npm notice 
jupyterlab-plotly-4.14.3.tgz

Yarn configuration loaded.
Node v15.12.0

Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
> node "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js" install --non-interactive
yarn install v1.15.2
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "jupyterlab-plotly > @lumino/widgets > @lumino/coreutils@1.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "crypto@1.0.1".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 9.81s.

> node "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js" yarn-deduplicate -s fewer
yarn run v1.15.2
error Command "yarn-deduplicate" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

> node "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js"
yarn install v1.15.2
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.52s.

> node "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js" run build:prod:minimize
yarn run v1.15.2
$ ensure-max-old-space webpack --config webpack.prod.minimize.config.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:352
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\which\which.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:344:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:557:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:910:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\buildutils\lib\ensure-max-old-space.js:28:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Szarka Roland\\anaconda3\\share\\jupyter\\lab\\staging\\node_modules\\which\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'which'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

JupyterLab failed to build
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

  File "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 105, in start
    command=command, app_options=app_options)

  File "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 459, in build
    command=command, clean_staging=clean_staging)

  File "C:\Users\Szarka Roland\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 669, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

Exiting application: jupyter
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Right extension for Plotly in JupyterLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604893/what-is-right-extension-for-plotly-in-jupyterlab)