# How can I generate a line animation for the stocks data using plotly?

Tags: python, animation, plotly

Hey I was trying to make an line animation for the stocks data built in plotly.
So I tried this code below following
https://plotly.com/python/animations/
but nothing shows.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y=df.columns[1:6], animation_frame = 'date')
fig.show()
```

what I intended to do was to make a line animation of the 6 company's stock price
with respect to the date. I'm totally new to plotly so this maybe a dumb question but I'd be grateful if you guys could help. Thank You!

Comment: Do you run it in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @DimKoim Yes I'm using jupyter notebook

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771328/plotly-chart-not-showing-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @DimKoim I tried but it doesn't work. I think there is a problem in my code but can't find out. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: What is the output when you print your `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

- you need some consistency across the animation frames for the xaxis and yaxis
- to achieve this I modified to use day of month as xaxis and ensured range is appropriate for all frames in yaxis
- then used month/year as the animation (a line only makes sense if there is more that one value to plot) so there are a collection of values in each frame

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.stocks()
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
fig = px.line(df, x = df["date"].dt.day, y=df.columns[1:6], animation_frame=df["date"].dt.strftime("%b-%Y"))
fig.update_layout(yaxis={"range":[0,df.iloc[:,1:6].max().max()]})
```