# fig.show() doesn't show the plot when using Candlestick

Tags: python, plotly-python, candlestick-chart

I have trouble to show the candlestick plot. I have tried `fig.show()` and `iplot(fig)` but they return a white screen! and when I try `plt.plot(fig)` I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Figure'`.
here is the code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

candlestick_data = data.groupby(data.Date.dt.date).agg({'Price':['min','max','first'
                                                           ,'last']})

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x = candlestick_data.index,
                                    open=candlestick_data['Price']['first'],
                                    high=candlestick_data['Price']['max'],
                                    low=candlestick_data['Price']['min'],
                                    close=candlestick_data['Price']['last'])
                     ])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, xaxis_title='Date',
                 yaxis_title='Price(USD$)', title='Bitcoin Candlestick Chart Over Past 30 Days')

fig.show() #returns white screen
```

this is how candlestick_data looks like:

[image: candlestick_data]

Comment: Which visualization library do you want to use, plotly, then of course the error will occur because the last line specifies matplotlib. Let's remove it. So I was trying your code with similar stock data. Are you using the latest version of plotly? Please run up to `fig.show()`.

Comment: even in that case still doesn't show the plot! I just wrote those 2 line after fig.show() to show I've tried those as well!

Comment: The last two lines are unnecessary. What version of Plotly are you currently using? The latest version is 5.17.0. That's how I got my graphs.

Comment: I have the same version!

Comment: I've figured it out! I am working on jupyter notebook and I have to change init_notebook_mode, Not sure why! @r-beginners Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in jupyter and based on suggestion provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771328/plotly-chart-not-showing-in-jupyter-notebook) I changed the notebook mode. So here is what I added to make it work for me:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
# Set notebook mode to work in offline
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
```