# No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser. Jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, ide, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter-notebook doesn't open a web browser. It worked just fine before, then after windows 10 prompted for an update it began to open in Microsoft edge. When I tried to change it to the default browser which is chrome now it won't open at all.

I followed [how to open Jupyter notebook in chrome on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829761/how-to-open-jupyter-notebook-in-chrome-on-windows) to try and change it back to chrome.

When I try and run

```
jupyter notebook
```

in cmd all I get is

```
[I 21:39:08.015 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\roy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 21:39:08.015 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\roy\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 21:39:08.015 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\roy
[I 21:39:08.015 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 21:39:08.015 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=d0a958999d7e59da3f097809882e8f40eb5845e3a07cebe8
[I 21:39:08.031 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 21:39:08.109 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/roy/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1516-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=d0a958999d7e59da3f097809882e8f40eb5845e3a07cebe8
```

However when I copy and paste the url in a web browser it just works fine.

Answer (score 19):

Solved it.

I went to the
.jupyter folder in my Users directory >
opened the jupyter_notebook_config.py file >
then edited this line from:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe '
```

to:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
```

Now it works well.

Comment: great! only here with you i found complete solution

Comment: The `u` prefix is not required in Python 3 (because Unicode strings are the default)

Comment: thanks for this solution - worked for me as well. can anyone explain why the / works in this case?

Answer (score 2):

This is a issue of tunneling.
Try this:

```
ssh username@xx.xx.xx.xx -NL 1234:localhost:1234
```

For more details, refer the below link:
https://medium.com/@apbetahouse45/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks-on-remote-server-part-1-ssh-a2be0232c533

Comment: In my case, `-N` prevented a connection being established. What worked for me is: `ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 <remote_host>`

Comment: @Sameen ggwp it worked

Comment: same for me as @sameen stated. I changed -NL to -L. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my similar issue when jupyter is installed under my python 2.7 directory, but is not necessary under the jupyter installed in my python 3.7 directory. Readers with a 3.7 directory may be encountering a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because by default program to open .html files was not a browser. I just had to tell my computer to always open .html files with a browser.