# Open Jupyter-Notebook with Specified Browser (Anaconda, Windows)

Tags: python, firefox, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I can't open jupyter-notebook from Anaconda prompt with a specified browser (i.e. not the default one) using

```
jupyter-notebook --browser=firefox
```

It says among other things "No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser." and gives me an URL which I can copy into the browser (which works).

This however opens Firefox:

```
start firefox
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56513564/9622398.

Comment: In addition, if the .jupyter folder does not contain a jupyter_notebook_config.py file, you can generate it with jupyter notebook --generate-config

Comment: Not sure what to do there. I found the following in the newly generated config, which seems different from what to expect according to your link and which seems to tell me it should allow for a specified browser as it is: ## Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the notebook.
#  If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the `webbrowser`
#  standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment
#  variable to override it.
#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''

Comment: I use Python 3 by the way.