# how can I open .ipynb(jupyter notebook) on chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm learning python now, and I don't figure out how to open .ipynb on chrome.
When I try to, the cells appear for just a second but disappear and a message **something went wrong with displaying webpage** comes out.
I can open another .ipynb on chrome via jupyter notebook home screen.
What's more, I confirmed that kernel started.

how can i fix this???

Comment: Have you performed the steps here: [jupyter on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829761/how-to-open-jupyter-notebook-in-chrome-on-windows)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.